# Get raw video frames from MPV (callback or render to specific memory address)

Tags: c, video-streaming, libvlc, mpv

There is [mpv player](https://mpv.io/) which is a fork of old MPlayer. It can be built as library and has API to render video frames to many video outputs such as OpenGL surface, Direct3D, SDL and others. I am trying to use this library in my current project to decode flv stream from cloud.

But i can't find a way to render decoded video frames direct to user-space allocated memory buffer. I need this option for specific reasons, and interfaces listed above aren't suitable for my task. I also need a callback which will be called after every frame is decoded and written in memory.

Is there any way to reach this functionality using standard mpv API from [libmpv/client.h](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/blob/master/libmpv/client.h)? If no, how to write simple [video out driver](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv/tree/master/video/out) and pass a pointer to custom memory to it?

I had used libVLC for my task already and it has [clear interface](https://www.videolan.org/developers/vlc/doc/doxygen/html/group__libvlc__media__player.html#ga612605f2e5c638d9f4ed59021d714bf0) to set up few callbacks for my needs, but unfortunately libVLC 2.x contains [bug with gray frames artifacts](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=117809) appearing during play video stream from cloud.